# What's the difference between just open Package.swift & use `swift package generate-xcodeproj` then open the generated xcodeproj file?

Tags: swift, xcode, vapor, swift-package-manager

I followed the Vapor Website Docs, created hello project.
[VaporDocs](https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/)

under hello project path, inputed `swift build` in terminal. But when open Package.swift, Xcode start to fetch vapor again.

Why? all dependencies repository is in `.build` path isn't? Why Xcode begains fetch Vapor over again?

`swift package generate-xcodeproj` can help generate xcode project, it seems like all dependencies is not package anymore. just groups.

What's the difference between just open Package.swift & use `swift package generate-xcodeproj` then open the generated xcodeproj file?

open Pacakge.swift with Xcode, fetch Vapor very slow. is there any better way?

like tell the Xcode everything is just in `./build` path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you work with a project in terminal you use commands like

```sh
swift package update
swift build
swift run
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

these commands works with hidden `.build` folder and Xcode project generated by `swift package generate-xcodeproj` works with that `.build` folder too. The only disadvantage of `xcodeproj` that if you change `Package.swift` or manually(outside of Xcode) add/delete some files from `Sources` folder then you have to run either just `swift package generate-xcodeproj` or `swift package update && swift package generate-xcodeproj`.

When you open project by double clicking on `Package.swift` it not uses classic xcodeproj anymore, now it is fully dynamic and you could edit `Package.swift` and files on-the-fly, doesn't matter in Xcode or in Finder, it will track all the changes. Though it sounds cool it works not perfectly and I still prefer classic `xcodeproj` cause it is not really hard to execute `swift package generate-xcodeproj` when needed. As far as I know there is no way to say Xcode to use `.build` folder in dynamic mode, it uses `DerivedData` folder to store dependencies.